# Tkinter can only be imported and run only once in Anaconda Windows10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10, anaconda

I am currently using anaconda and spyder to program python script. When I try to use tkinter. It can run only once. When I try to run the script the second time. It shows the error log: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)
```

The below is the error message I got from spyder console.

```py
from Tkinter import Tk
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

Comment: `from Tkinter import Tk` will not work in python 3 (your tag) - you must use `from tkinter import Tk` (with a small **t**)

Answer (score 0):

Import Tips:
`from tkinter import *`
`import tkinter`

This works in 3.6 and 3.7